# How to add a button in table

Tags: php, html, sql

right now I have a page which displays homework set by teachers from a database. The students must be able to see all their homework on this page, with the due date and set date. As of now, it's working and after the due date, the task turns red, which is fine. However, I need to now add a small box or button which can be clicked by the student once they have completed the task. Once this is done, It would delete it ONLY for the student which has clicked it.

```
    <?php
    include_once("connection.php"); //including the database connection file
    $id= $_GET['id'];
    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM homework WHERE class_id=? ORDER BY datedue DESC");
    $result->bind_param("i", $id);
    $result->execute();
    $result2 = $result->get_result();?>
<html>
<head>    
    <title>View IS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table width='80%' border=0>
        <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
            <td>Task</td>
            <td>Date Set </td>
            <td>Date Due </td>
            <td><button type="button">Click Me!</button></td>

        </tr>
        <?php
            while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {   
                if (strtotime(date("d-m-Y")) > strtotime($res['datedue'])) {
                    echo "<tr style=\"color: red;\">";
                        echo "<td>".$res['description']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$res['dateset']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$res['datedue']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".<button type=button>Click Me!</button>."</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                } else {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>".$res['description']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$res['dateset']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$res['datedue']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".<button type=button>Click Me!</button>."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
```

How can I do this? Thank you
[image: database]

Comment: "Once this is done, It would delete it. "  if you do this, the task will be delete for all student, then what about the student who did not completed the task.

Comment: Yes, my bad that is what I meant. I will re write my question.

Comment: sounds like one update for user...

Comment: But wouldn't that update for everyone? I want it to only stop showing the task for the person who clicked it.

Comment: You don't need to repeat all the code for each tr, just for the td where the button should appear.

Comment: ya but you need to know who have cliked...so if you have user log, you can se the task for all users.. if user X click, remove from user X, or just update tha stat for that user...

Comment: dose each student have a ID, i mean do you have student table in db.

Comment: I'll add my database too.

Comment: the studant have to make login to see the tasks?

Comment: @NoobDEV-GBL Yes

Comment: host in some place that user_id_X complete task_id on date_x, then if he have that taskid, ingnore on load tasks...

Comment: in this case what i would do is add an extra column like "student_complete", update the column with each student ID clicked as an array. so then you can check if the student ID exists in the array and remove that row in the home work table loop

Comment: @Ramyz right, that shoud make it work fine on the spot

Comment: @Ramyz  I'm new to programming, and I don't really get what you're saying. Could you explain it a bit more? Thanks

Comment: OK !! let me put answer in few minutes

Comment: How do u get Student ID, when logged in, is it store in session

Comment: @Ramyz No, The ID in tbluser is stored in a session tho. From there I can get the studentID correspoding to tbluser_ID in 'student' table  right?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't test this, can you give this a try and let me know if error occurs

create new field name '**stud_completed**' in homework table

***homework.php*** page

```
<?php
        include_once("connection.php"); //including the database connection file
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM homework WHERE class_id=? ORDER BY datedue DESC");
        $result->bind_param("i", $id);
        $result->execute();
        $result2 = $result->get_result();
        $todayDate = strtotime(date("d-m-Y"));
        $Log_student = $_SESSION['studentID'];
?>
    <html>
    <head>    
        <title>View IS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width='80%' border=0>
            <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
                <td>Task</td>
                <td>Date Set </td>
                <td>Date Due </td>
                <td>Action</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
                    $redDueTask = null; // each loop $redDueTask will be set to NULL
                    $homeworkID = $res['id']; // Get the DueDate of each task
                    $dueDate = strtotime($res['datedue']); // Get the DueDate of each task
                    if ($todayDate > $dueDate) { $redDueTask = 'style="color: red;"'; } // Set $redDueTask if task has past duedate

                    $student_completed = explode(',',$res['stud_completed']); // get the coma seperated completed student list and convert it to array
                    if (!in_array($Log_student, $student_completed)) {  // chk if logged in student ID is in array and if not in the list show task 
            ?>
            <tr <?php echo $redDueTask?>>
                <td><?php echo $res['description']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $res['dateset']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $res['datedue']?></td>
                <td>
                <?php if (isset($redDueTask)) { // $redDueTask will bset if the task duedate has passed, so no need compelete button ?>
                    Time UP!
                <?php } else { // $redDueTask is not set then show compelete button ?>
                    <a href="taskdone.php?tid=<?php echo $homeworkID ?>"><button type='button'>Have Complete</button></a>
                <?php } ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </body>
```

***taskdone.php*** page

```
<?php
                include_once("connection.php"); //including the database connection file
                $tid = $_GET['tid']; // Get Homework Task ID from URL
                $Log_student = $_SESSION['studentID']; // Get Loggedin Student ID from Session

                // Get ROW Statment
                $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM homework WHERE id=?");
                $result->bind_param('i', $tid);
                $result->execute();
                $result2 = $result->get_result();
                $res = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);        
                $stud_completed = $res['stud_completed']; // Get the current List of completed student
                if ($stud_completed == "") { // If stud_completed is null or blank
                    $stud_completed = $Log_student;  // add the current student ID with out coma
                } else {
                    $stud_completed .= "," . $Log_student;  // Inculde the current logged in student ID with coma
                }

                // Update ROW Statement
                $sql = "UPDATE homework SET stud_completed=? WHERE id=?";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bind_param('i', $stud_completed, $tid);
                if ($stmt->execute()) { 
                    header("homework.php"); // if GOT updated go to home work task list page 
                }
        ?>
```

Comment: My SESSIONS were not working for some reason, so I just put the student ID in the url instead `$Log_student= $_GET['studid']; ` then on the bottom    `<a href="taskdone.php?tid=<?php echo $homeworkID ?>&studid=<?php echo $Log_student?>"><button type='button'>Have Complete</button></a>`

Comment: Ok. That will fine too

Comment: But now, its just a blank page

Comment: When I press task done, url become http://localhost/sswl/student/taskdone.php?tid=16&studid=51 and its blank. But you helped me a lot, its probably hard to understand what isnt working from my comment.

Comment: Oh  ok, is the stud_completed column meant to be empty?

Comment: First it should be. I mean for the first student who complete

Comment: Remove the dot before equal sign from the first statement if $stud_completed is empty

Comment: Ok, I changed `$stmt->bind_param('i', $stud_completed, $id);` to `$stmt->bind_param('i', $stud_completed, $tid);`, and now in my table, stud_completed actually has the students number in it. However, I can still see the homework.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh. Ok. Happy to help